# why keyboard dismiss instantly when textinput pressed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

Here is my code.

```
<Modal>
...
                            <TextInput
                                keyboardType="phone-pad"
                                placeholder={i18n.t('PhoneNumber')}
                                style={styles.modalTextPhoneNo}
                                onChangeText={(text) => setshareToPhone(text)}//useState
                            />
...
</Modal>
...
    modalTextPhoneNo: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: 15,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: colors.primary,
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderBottomColor: colors.secondary,
    },
```

When my app loaded, and press on the textinput for the first time, keyboard will dismiss instantly. After the first time, it works well, even when I navigated to other page and back to this page.

Also, textInput caret sometimes is centered sometimes not. Cannot find any pattern when will happened.

I have more TextInput on other page and they don't have the same problems. Only thing different is this textInput is wrapped with Modal.

Comment: Can you share some of the non-UI code? Usually keyboard closing is the result of something taking focus away. Is there anything else loading/ displaying? Could the modal be taking focus?

Comment: try to wrap your textinput into view component.